# changing a theme (not working)

Tags: css, jsp

I am applying different themes to my project. I have maintained 2 set of css files, 1set of css files contain RED theme another set contain BLUE theme,once the user selects the theme option it should affect for each and every jsp page. But the problem i am facing is selected theme is affecting only for current page instead of all pages.

MainMenu.jsp

```
$(window).load(function(){
     $('.blueTheme').click(function (){

           $('link[href="css/mainDiv.css"]').attr('href','css-blue/mainDiv.css');
           $('link[href="css/style.css"]').attr('href','css-blue/style.css');
           $('link[href="css/style12.css"]').attr('href','css-blue/style12.css');
           $('link[href="css/templatemo_style.css"]').attr('href','css-blue/templatemo_style.css');

        });
        $('.redTheme').click(function (){
           $('link[href="css-blue/mainDiv.css"]').attr('href','css/mainDiv.css');
           $('link[href="css-blue/style.css"]').attr('href','css/style.css');
           $('link[href="css-blue/style12.css"]').attr('href','css/style12.css');
           $('link[href="css-blue/templatemo_style.css"]').attr('href','css/templatemo_style.css');
        });
});
```

I am calling MainMenu.jsp to remaining pages.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the chosen theme you need to put the selected color somewhere and read from there in the other themed jsps. If it can be transient you can use `session`, if you need it to be persistent (if the user logs out for example) it has to go on the database. Depending on your requirement a `cookie` could do the job too.